# Rails - error " An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.13), and Bundler cannot continue"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I am totally new to Git and Ruby on Rails and I'm doing the "The Odin Project", but I've got stucked.

I am trying to deploy the application I've created, using Git to push the master branch up to Heroku.

When I run the command "git push heroku master" I get this log with the follwing mistakes, what it may be?

```
matteo@matteo-VirtualBox:~/railsbridge/hello_app$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 90, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (76/76), done.
Writing objects: 100% (90/90), 22.03 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 90 (delta 6), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote:  !     Warning: Multiple default buildpacks reported the ability to handle this app. The first buildpack in the list below will be used.
remote:             Detected buildpacks: Ruby,Node.js
remote:             See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#buildpack-detect-order
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.3.4
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.15.2
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.15.4). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
remote:        Fetching rake 12.1.0
remote:        Installing concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
remote:        Fetching minitest 5.10.3
....
remote:        Installing turbolinks 5.0.1
remote:        Fetching activesupport 5.1.4
remote:        The latest bundler is 1.16.0.pre.3, but you are currently running 1.15.2.
remote:        To update, run `gem install bundler --pre`
remote:        Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
remote:        current directory:
remote:        /tmp/build_c400101f4282a4c7d4222ce20d2d35b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/ext/sqlite3
remote:        /tmp/build_c400101f4282a4c7d4222ce20d2d35b2/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/bin/ruby -r
remote:        ./siteconf20171015-278-1swne7x.rb extconf.rb
remote:        checking for sqlite3.h... no
remote:        sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'brew install sqlite3',
remote:        'yum install sqlite-devel' or 'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev'
remote:        and check your shared library search path (the
remote:        location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
remote:        *** extconf.rb failed ***
remote:        Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
remote:        libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
remote:        need configuration options.
remote:        Provided configuration options:
remote:        --with-opt-dir
remote:        --srcdir=.
remote:        --curdir
remote:        --ruby=/tmp/build_c400101f4282a4c7d4222ce20d2d35b2/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
remote:        --with-sqlite3-config
remote:        --without-sqlite3-config
remote:        --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
remote:        To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can
remote:        be found here:
remote:        /tmp/build_c400101f4282a4c7d4222ce20d2d35b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/sqlite3-1.3.13/mkmf.log
remote:        extconf failed, exit code 1
remote:        Gem files will remain installed in
remote:        /tmp/build_c400101f4282a4c7d4222ce20d2d35b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13
remote:        for inspection.
remote:        Results logged to
remote:        /tmp/build_c400101f4282a4c7d4222ce20d2d35b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/sqlite3-1.3.13/gem_make.out
remote:        An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.13), and Bundler cannot
remote:        continue.
remote:        Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.13'` succeeds before bundling.
remote:        In Gemfile:
remote:        sqlite3
remote:        Bundler Output: Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.15.4). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
remote:        Fetching rake 12.1.0
remote:        Fetching concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
1.4
remote:        Fetching rb-inotify 0.9.10
remote:        Installing rb-inotify 0.9.10
remote:        The latest bundler is 1.16.0.pre.3, but you are currently running 1.15.2.
remote:        To update, run `gem install bundler --pre`
remote:        Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
remote:        
remote:        current directory:
remote:        /tmp/build_c400101f4282a4c7d4222ce20d2d35b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/ext/sqlite3
remote:        /tmp/build_c400101f4282a4c7d4222ce20d2d35b2/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/bin/ruby -r
remote:        ./siteconf20171015-278-1swne7x.rb extconf.rb
remote:        checking for sqlite3.h... no
remote:        sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'brew install sqlite3',
remote:        'yum install sqlite-devel' or 'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev'
remote:        and check your shared library search path (the
remote:        location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
remote:        *** extconf.rb failed ***
remote:        Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
remote:        libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
remote:        need configuration options.
remote:        
remote:        Provided configuration options:
remote:        --with-opt-dir
remote:        --without-opt-dir
remote:        --ruby=/tmp/build_c400101f4282a4c7d4222ce20d2d35b2/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
remote:        --with-sqlite3-config
remote:        --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
remote:        
remote:        To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can
remote:        be found here:
remote:        
remote:        /tmp/build_c400101f4282a4c7d4222ce20d2d35b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/sqlite3-1.3.13/mkmf.log
remote:        
remote:        extconf failed, exit code 1
remote:        
remote:        Gem files will remain installed in
remote:        /tmp/build_c400101f4282a4c7d4222ce20d2d35b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13
remote:        for inspection.
remote:        Results logged to
remote:        /tmp/build_c400101f4282a4c7d4222ce20d2d35b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/sqlite3-1.3.13/gem_make.out
remote:        
remote:        An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.13), and Bundler cannot
remote:        continue.
remote:        Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.13'` succeeds before bundling.
remote:        
remote:        In Gemfile:
remote:        sqlite3
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !     Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku:
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to murmuring-river-60914.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/murmuring-river-60914.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/murmuring-river-60914.git'
```

I have followed the tutorial instruction by setting the Gemfile with this inside:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.13'
  gem 'byebug',  '9.0.0', platform: :mri
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.20.0'
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multiple buildpacks, remove all of them and then set the Ruby one:

```
$ heroku buildpacks:clear
$ heroku buildpacks:set heroku/ruby
```

About [SQLite on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3):

> SQLite runs in memory, and backs up its data store in files on disk.
>   While this strategy works well for development, Heroku’s Cedar stack
>   has an ephemeral filesystem. You can write to it, and you can read
>   from it, but the contents will be cleared periodically. If you were to
>   use SQLite on Heroku, you would lose your entire database at least
>   once every 24 hours.

So, for the message

> sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'brew install sqlite3'`

replace the `sqlite3` gem for `pg` in your Gemfile, then edit the database.yml file:

```
# Gemfile
gem 'pg'

# config/database.yml
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: your_project_name_dev

test:
  <<: *default
  database: your_project_name_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: your_project_name_prod
```

Probably you'll need to clean the tmp/ folder, so you can delete the Gemfile.lock file and run the rails commands for that:

```
$ rm -rf Gemfile.lock
$ rails tmp:clear
$ rails tmp:create
```

Comment: I have made these changes but it seems to get to the same errors...can I leave "your_project_name" in database.yml or should I put something specific at its place?

Comment: I recommend you to remove the Gemfile.lock file and run bundle install again. `your_project_name` is the name that takes the database, can be anything that just adapts the name specification.

Comment: when I run $ heroku buildpacks:remove heroku/nodejs I get:  ▸    heroku-cli: update available from 6.13.18 to 6.14.34-1fcf80e
 ▸    No buildpacks were found. Next release on murmuring-river-60914 will
 ▸    detect buildpack normally.       Can be smt related to this?

Comment: Run `heroku buildpacks:clear && heroku buildpacks:set heroku/ruby` what do you get?

Comment: ▸    heroku-cli: update available from 6.13.18 to 6.14.34-1fcf80e
Buildpacks cleared. Next release on murmuring-river-60914 will detect buildpack normally.
 ▸    heroku-cli: update available from 6.13.18 to 6.14.34-1fcf80e
Buildpack set. Next release on murmuring-river-60914 will use heroku/ruby.
Run git push heroku master to create a new release using this buildpack.

Comment: Okay, so run `git push heroku master` now.

Comment: eventually ends up like before...`
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !     Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku:
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: ! Push rejected to murmuring-river-60914.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156770/discussion-between-sebastian-palma-and-naufragio).